# join two pandas dataframe using a specific column

Tags: python, join, pandas, dataframe

I am new with pandas and I am trying to join two dataframes based on the equality of one specific column. For example suppose that I have the followings:

```
df1
A    B    C
1    2    3
2    2    2

df2
A    B    C
5    6    7
2    8    9
```

Both dataframes have the same columns and the value of only one column (say A) might be equal. What I want as output is this:

```
df3
A    B    C   B    C
2    8    9   2    2
```

The values for column 'A' are unique in both dataframes.

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
pd.concat([df1.set_index('A'),df2.set_index('A')], axis=1, join='inner')
```

If you wish to maintain column `A` as a non-index, then:

```
pd.concat([df1.set_index('A'),df2.set_index('A')], axis=1, join='inner').reset_index()
```

Comment: With this good method - A becomes the index.  This may be what the OP wants, but you might also offer use of `reset_index` to turn it into a column if that's what is wanted.

Comment: Sure, the index can be reset by adding `.reset_index()` at the end.

`pd.concat([df1.set_index('A'),df2.set_index('A')], axis=1, join='inner').reset_index()`

Comment: yup - that's what I was getting at :)

Answer (score 32):

Alternatively, you could just do:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='A', how='inner', suffixes=('_1', '_2'))
```

And then you can keep track of each value's origin

Comment: What does suffixes do?

Comment: addes a suffix to each column name so that you're not left with e.g. two columns called `"B"`. When you have duplicate column names, you get very unexpected behavior with say, `df3['B'].apply(lambda x: ...)` since now `df['B']` is a DataFrame and not a Series.

Comment: Awesome. That actually helps alot

Comment: Works great. tnx :)